# Is the answer $5!-2\cdot 3! \cdot {4 \choose 1}$ or $5!-2\cdot 3! \cdot 4$ (multiplication rule in combinatorics)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

How many ways can five different people M,N,O,Q,P sit together such that NQ are not together?

You can do 5!-unfavorable cases.

Pretend [NQ] is one person [NQ]_ _ _ and there are four positions.
Three people have the choices $3!$

N and Q may re-arrange positions which is a double.

Is this multiplication principle or binomial coefficient $4$ choose $1$ for [NQ] either goes in the first, between the others, or last?

Is the answer $5!-2\cdot 3! \cdot {4 \choose 1}$ or $5!-2\cdot 3! \cdot 4$?

Comment: $\binom41=4$. What is exactly your question?

Comment: simply 5!-2*4! since you view NQ one person, although it is the same answer